# html javascript css Magnifying glass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var native_width = 0;
 var native_height = 0;

 //Now the mousemove function
 $(".magnify").mousemove(function(e){
  //When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
  //the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
  //are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
  if(!native_width && !native_height)
  {
   //This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
   //We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
   //width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
   //created this image object.
   var image_object = new Image();
   image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");
   
   //This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
   //width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
   //the image gets loaded.
   native_width = image_object.width;
   native_height = image_object.height;
  }
  else
  {
   //x/y coordinates of the mouse
   //This is the position of .magnify with respect to the document.
   var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
   //We will deduct the positions of .magnify from the mouse positions with
   //respect to the document to get the mouse positions with respect to the 
   //container(.magnify)
   var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
   var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;
   
   //Finally the code to fade out the glass if the mouse is outside the container
   if(mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0)
   {
    $(".large").fadeIn(100);
   }
   else
   {
    $(".large").fadeOut(100);
   }
   if($(".large").is(":visible"))
   {
    //The background position of .large will be changed according to the position
    //of the mouse over the .small image. So we will get the ratio of the pixel
    //under the mouse pointer with respect to the image and use that to position the 
    //large image inside the magnifying glass
    var rx = Math.round(mx/$(".small").width()*native_width - $(".large").width()/2)*-1;
    var ry = Math.round(my/$(".small").height()*native_height - $(".large").height()/2)*-1;
    var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";
    
    //Time to move the magnifying glass with the mouse
    var px = mx - $(".large").width()/2;
    var py = my - $(".large").height()/2;
    //Now the glass moves with the mouse
    //The logic is to deduct half of the glass's width and height from the 
    //mouse coordinates to place it with its center at the mouse coordinates
    
    //If you hover on the image now, you should see the magnifying glass in action
    $(".large").css({left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp});
   }
  }
 })
})
```

```css
/*Some CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.magnify {width: 200px; margin: 50px auto; position: relative;}

/*Lets create the magnifying glass*/
.large {
 width: 175px; height: 175px;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 100%;
 
 /*Multiple box shadows to achieve the glass effect*/
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 
 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 
 inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 
 /*Lets load up the large image first*/
 background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg') no-repeat;
 
 /*hide the glass by default*/
 display: none;
}

/*To solve overlap bug at the edges during magnification*/
.small { display: block; }
```

```html
<!-- Lets make a simple image magnifier -->
<div class="magnify">
 <div>I want to magnify whole page Including text image and everything</div>
 <!-- This is the magnifying glass which will contain the original/large version -->
 <div class="large"></div>
 
 <!-- This is the small image -->
 <img class="small" src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg" width="200"/>
 
</div>

<!-- Lets load up prefixfree to handle CSS3 vendor prefixes -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- You can download it from http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/ -->

<!-- Time for jquery action -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I want magnifying glass magnify whole webpage not only image. the magnifying glass magnify everything on page images text video. And doesn't disappear when nothing on div or webpage.

Here is the jsfiddle...

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ckc5r7sp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im using anythingzoomer to accomplish what you need. It is able to magnify text and images. It requires to have duplicate html elements to complete the magnify.

Here is where you can learn more about and its documentation
[AnythingZoomer](https://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/use.php)

HTML

```
<p><strong>Image with Text Demo</strong></p>

<div id="zoom">

    <div class="small">
        <p>hello</p>
        <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg"  />
    </div>

    <div class="large">
        <p>hello</p>
         <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg"   />
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
/* This is where to style the magnification to a circle*/
.az-windowed {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 
    0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 
    inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

[The Code in Action - Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/KwvjL/2051/)

Comment: [Jsfiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/hb1xzje1/3/) **(replace .small into body) but it was not in a box or circle just like before**

Comment: I thought he wanted per element? Thats why I separated it into a div and img o_O

Comment: no, i want to magnifying glass that magnify whole page (body) but in a sphere just like [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ckc5r7sp/)

Comment: Please be more specify remove dblclick if you can. if it's not possible then no problem ;) It's alright and Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome! Was not aware that happens lol. This can be disable by having switchEvent : 'disable' as one of the parameters. http://jsfiddle.net/KwvjL/2052/

Comment: I there any way to avoid twice content. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7e762zxt/1/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93322/discussion-between-qasim-ali-and-kelv-gonzales).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the display in the magnifying glass doesnt align with the normal sized content on the y axis. This might have something to do with the math part of your solution.
You can even see normal sized image in the glass at the bottom.